# Is there onsen ui intellisense extension for visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, onsen-ui, taco

will there be ONSEN UI IntelliSense support for visual studio?
or how do we manually add ONSEN UI's element to Visual Studio IntelliSense extension?
thanks.

Comment: No updates about this issue: https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/1046

Comment: Thanks for response.